# Какие знаки препинания нужны в последней строчке?

Tags: пунктуация

Ветер спину и плечи щекочет,

Потому что иду без рубашки

По тропинке, бегущей куда-то

***За овраг() через рощу() до брода***...

*Какие знаки препинания нужны в последней строчке?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

Ветер спину и плечи щекочет,

Потому что иду без рубашки

По тропинке, бегущей (1) куда-то

За овраг, (2)через рощу, (3)до брода...

Местоимение "куда-то" отнесем к первому обстоятельству,  а три обстоятельств будем считать **однородными**, раскрывающими тему направления движения.